# Compact metric spaces can be covered by finitely many $\epsilon$-balls

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space, show:

i) For any $\epsilon>0$ there are $n \in \mathbb N$ and $ x_{1},..., x_{n} \in X $ so that $X=\bigcup_{j=1}^{n}B_{\epsilon}(x_{j})$

My thoughts so far (not much):

Since $X$ is a compact space there exists $\bigcup_{j=1}^{N}U_{\lambda_{j}}$ such that $X \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^{N}U_{\lambda_{j}}$.

A huge help would be to say that $\bigcup_{j=1}^{N}U_{\lambda_{j}} \subset X$, but that does not hold right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT: if $X$ is compact then for **any** open cover there is a finite subcover. Now just choose the open cover defined by $\mathcal B(\epsilon):=\{\Bbb B(x,\epsilon):x\in X\}$ for any chosen $\epsilon>0$.

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't say what the $U_{\lambda_j}$'s are, nothing much can be said about your attempt.

Just consider the set$$\left\{B_\varepsilon(x)\,\middle|\,x\in X\right\}.$$It's an open cover of $X$ and $X$ is compact. Therefore…

Comment: Hello!! So we consider this set as an open cover (this means that $X=\{B_{\epsilon}(x)\mid x\in X\}$, right? ) and since $X$ is compact and each open cover has a finite subcover, we get that there finite many points $x_1,\ldots ,x_n\in X$ such that $X=\cup_{i=1}^nB_{\epsilon}(x_i)$ ?

Comment: Yes, except that don't *consider* this set as an open cover. It *is* an open cover.

Comment: Ahh ok! One other question. If we just have that there is a finite cover (we don't have that $X$ is compact) how do we show that $(X,d)$ is bounded?

Comment: The union of finitely many bounded sets is always bounded. So, since each $B_\varepsilon(x)$ is bounded, the whole space is bounded.

Comment: Ah so in general the epsilon balls $B_{\epsilon}$ are always bounded, right?

Comment: Yes, since the distance between any two of its points is always smaller than $2\varepsilon$.

Comment: Ahh I understand! In general it holds that if $(X,d)$ is bounded and complete thenit is compact, right? We have that : A metric space X is complete if every Cauchy sequence in X is convergent to a point in X. A set A ⊆ X is compact if every sequence {xn} has a subsequence which converges to a point of A.To get the result we need the boundness?

Comment: An infinite set endowed with the discrete metric is complete and bounded, but it is not compact. But a complete metric space is compact is and only if it is [totally bounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_bounded_space).

Comment: Thank you very much !!! :-)